# How to use a model in routes without using the model's constant?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'd like to use a model in my `routes.rb` file without actually calling the model's constant. The intent is to not cause Rails to examine the database when accessing the routes file, since it somehow causes unexpected behavior during an edge case of an unmigrated server described below.

For now, I have a line of code that uses the model's constant, but I just commented it out before the first migration, and it works fine. But I feel there might be a better practice, so I'd like to know: are there other ways to use a method from a model without using the model's constant in the route file?

Currently, my routes file looks like:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  # …
  get 'universal' => 'novels#edit', defaults: { id: Novel.fetch_universal.id }
end
```

While this file works perfectly fine after migrating, the line with the model name constant `Novel` must be commented out before any ***new*** database can be migrated. If not commented out, then rails will attempt to check the novels table in the database before any database action (even including dropping the database with `rake db:drop`) and will throw an error that the table 'novels' is not found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with following I guess,

```
{ id: (ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables.include?('novels') ? Novel.fetch_universal.id : [] }
```

It should work, not tested!

Comment: This worked swimmingly! It does need some minor edits, since the code doesn't run as is. But, thanks!

Comment: I wound up with: `{ id: (Novel.fetch_universal.id if ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables.include?('novels')) }`
where `Novel.fetch_universal` is never nil, since it creates the 'universal' if it does not exist. The default value such as `[]` shown does not matter, since this line is never evaluated fully before the migrations.

Comment: @RWDJ no for false condition it will return nil and will be evaluated as { id: nil } but okay if works in your case!